# Find Point in Polygon

Tags: arcgis-android

I am working with ArcGIS Android..Offline Geodatabase. I have Point as a graphics and Polygon layer as a feature layer.I want to find out Point in Polygon?

I have used the following code :

```
query = new QueryParameters();
               query.setOutFields(new String[] { "*" });
               query.setSpatialRelationship(SpatialRelationship.INTERSECTS);
               query.setGeometry(mapPoint);
               query.setInSpatialReference(mMapView.getSpatialReference());
               QueryTask qTask = new QueryTask(**featureLayerEight**);
```

I am getting following error:

> Error:(276, 34) error: no suitable constructor found for
>   QueryTask(FeatureLayer) constructor
>   QueryTask.QueryTask(String,UserCredentials) is not applicable (actual
>   and formal argument lists differ in length) constructor
>   QueryTask.QueryTask(String) is not applicable

(actual argument FeatureLayer cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the way around;
-OnClick of graphics I am searching point is in which polygon.

```
featureLayer***.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SelectionMode.NEW, new CallbackListener<FeatureResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCallback(FeatureResult objects) { **RESULT***}
});
```